# MATLAB editor does not work after using `matlab-emacs`

Tags: matlab, emacs

My MATLAB editor stopped working. I'm not able to open any file via UI or command (`edit file.m`). It all started when I was editing a script using `matlab-emacs`.

I found a workaround to open files, but it is annoying. First, I need to click with the right button of the mouse in the file I want to open. Then, I select `Compare against > Choose`. Clicking in one of the line numbers in the left panel opens the MATLAB editor. Once I'm in the editor, I can open any other file by choosing `File > Open as Text...`. I also tried reinstalling MATLAB, but the problem remained.

I am using MATLAB R2011a and Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent a big amount of time reinstalling it, when it was far more simple.

1. Select `File > Preferences...`
2. In `Editor/Debugger`, my editor was set as a blank `Text editor`, instead of `MATLAB Editor`.
3. Just pick `MATLAB Editor` in the radio button.

[image: MATLAB Editor]

`matlab-emacs` extension probably changed my settings.

Comment: Seems to me that `matlab-emacs` changed the settings for you rather than them mysteriously changing themselves ?